# Find the index of the first 1 in an array which contains only 1s and 0s, all the 0s being to the left side of the array, and all the 1s to the right?

Tags: python, algorithm

The task is to find the index of the first 1 in an array which contains only 1s and 0s with all the 0s being to the left side of the array, and all the 1s to the right.

For instance, if the list was, [0,0,0,0,1,1], the answer would be 4.

The time taken must be logarithmic.

I tried implementing the logic that if the middle number was 0, we look only look at the second half of the list. If on the other hand, the middle number was 1, we look at only the first half of the list. We keep doing this till we only have one number left.

```
def first1(lst):
  start_val=0
  end_val=len(lst)
  midpoint=(end_val+start_val)//2
  while end_val-start_val>1:
    if lst[midpoint]==1:
      endval=midpoint-1
      midpoint=start_val+end_val//2
    else:
      startval=midpoint+1
      midpoint=start_val+end_val//2
  return midpoint
```

This gives me an infinite loop. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You'll kick yourself when you read this. You initialize variables start_val and end_val, but you assign endpoint + 1 to startval and endval (no underscore in the variable name).

Otherwise, it works fine. I didn't see it immediately, so I put a print statement in the loop along with a 1 second delay so I could see what was going on. Also, I formatted your code a bit to make it more readable, mostly following the recommendations for putting spaces between variables and operators.

```
import time
def first1(lst):
  start_val = 0
  end_val = len(lst)
  midpoint = (end_val + start_val) // 2
  while end_val - start_val > 1:
    if lst[midpoint] == 1:
      end_val = midpoint - 1
      midpoint = (start_val + end_val) // 2
    else:
      start_val = midpoint + 1
      midpoint = (start_val + end_val) // 2
    print(start_val, midpoint, end_val)
    time.sleep(1)
  return midpoint

print(first1([0,0,0,0,1,1]))
```

Comment: I am still getting a list index out of range error.

Answer (score 1):

the reason that you are having this issue is because on the line

```
endval=midpoint-1
```

and the line

```
startval=midpoint+1
```

you are missing underscores in start_val and end_val.
however due to the methond you are using this will not work if the length is not a power of 2

Answer (score 0):

You can consider your array as sorted and use a binary search algorithm.  This will give you an O(log(N)) time complexity.

For example:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

a = [0,0,0,0,1,1]
p = bisect_left(a,1)
print(p) # 4
```

If you're not allowed to use Python modules, you can write your own binary search:

```
def find1(array):
    lo,hi  = 0,len(array)-1
    while hi>=lo:
        mid = (hi+lo)//2
        if array[mid]: hi = mid-1
        else:          lo = mid+1
    return hi+1

find1([0,0,0,0,1,1]) # 4
```

Comment: Re: "You can consider your array as sorted and use a binary search algorithm": Indeed, that is exactly what (s)he is doing.